# log4net - Tracing problems with logging configuration

Tags: c#, com, log4net, log4net-configuration, component-services

I have a .NET object that is COM visible and installed in a component services application to make it visible for some legacy code.

The component services application is configured with an application root directory.

In the application root directory I have an application.config file.

IN the application.config file I have

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\application\Logs\legacycomponents.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName} %date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="7" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

My code includes:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Log4Net Logging component
    /// </summary>
    protected ILog Logger
    {
        get
        {
            return LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
        }
    }
```

I'm then logging very verbosely at various levels throughout my code.

And it's not logging anything.

I've enabled log4net internal debug:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And monitored with debugview, which shows that log4net has done something:

```
[3064] log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository for assembly [Legacy.Component, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1916d4122ec2e2e8] 
[3064] log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [Legacy.Component=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1916d4122ec2e2e8] Loaded From [C:\product\ASP\bin\legacy.component.dll] 
[3064] log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [Legacy.Component, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1916d4122ec2e2e8] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified. 
[3064] log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [Legacy.Component=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1916d4122ec2e2e8] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy] 
[3064] log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: repository [log4net-default-repository] already exists, using repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
```

Which is as clear as mud :)

So I can't see anything else to check to see why I'm not getting any logging out of my object.

I can't find any better troubleshooting information anywhere currently.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you did, but just to make sure. Did you run this command too ?

```
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

This command load your log4net configuration, whithout it, it can't be done.

Also, I enable the debug option like that :

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="rollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="Logs\log.txt"/>
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
        <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd"/>
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="rollingFile"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Argh. Usually that's already been called so the assembly inherits the current state. In the legacy com mounted wrapper, that wasn't happening. Now working thanks.